# How to create reusable cards in powerpoint?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I have been creating some cards in PowerPoint as in the following.
[image]

I want to use this card as a placeholder and make many such cards in the PowerPoint slides.  Let us say that I have 10 such cards to be used throughout my presentation.

How do I make such a dynamic card in PowerPoint?

I have tried to create a slide master slide, but that seems to be fixed and may not be able to move the card wherever you need, and also may not be possible to create as many you need while creating the content.

Any suggestion? Or anyone has thought of any alternative to this scenario?

Comment: Work with a new Layout rather than the master. Don't insert the actual picture and text you want; instead, insert a picture placeholder and a text placeholder. These will both be editable when  you return to Normal view and insert new slides based on this layout.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Yes! I did try that. But, I am sure that wont be answering quite well for my situation since I want to have the card and I want to reuse it, may be, in the same slide n number of times, as any css will let me do it.

Comment: >>  I want to reuse it, may be, in the same slide 
In the same slide ... that makes a big difference; In that case, PPT won't help much. You'll probably have to create a sample card, then copy/paste it to the same slide or to other slides as needed.

Comment: You can group the contents of the card and copy-paste them to other slides. I believe that it would fulfill your objective in a very efficient manner. PowerPoint doesn't have an asset library of sorts for these though.